# Show Ansible Debug MSG as a list when looping through

Tags: ansible

How can I show ansible register debug logs as a list when using debug. Right now when it loops through it returns "msg" as separate but I want a list as show below.

```
  - name: Show created VM's
    debug:
      msg: "Created VM - {{ item.invocation.module_args.tags.hostname }}"
    with_items: "{{ azure_nic.results }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.tags.hostname }}"
```

Creates the following output:

```
TASK [Show created VM's] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/azure_ansible/azure_playbook.yaml:120
ok: [localhost] => (item=image-201) => {
    "msg": "Created VM - image-201"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=image-202) => {
    "msg": "Created VM - image-202"
}
```

But I want the output to be in a list like below:

```
"msg": 
 - "Created VM - image-201"
 - "Created VM - image-202"
```

Comment: @Rob. You removed "Ansible" from the titel of the question. You commented ``"Do not put tags in title."`` Is this a site policy? If so, would it be possible to post a link?

Comment: Yes, it is policy that's been here for years so don't recall the location but try here [ask]

Comment: For the record. See [Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: You should probably change the title to something similar to ``Show Ansible debug msg as a list when looping through.`` See the link above. This way it's "in a conversational tone". (Thinking about common sense. Consider ``tags: ansible, python`` and ``title: Show debug msg ...`` Is the question about Ansible or Python?)

Comment: Updated the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jinja template, e.g.

```yaml
  - name: Show created VM's
    debug:
      msg: |
        {% for item in azure_nic.results %}
        - Created VM - {{ item.invocation.module_args.tags.hostname }}
        {% endfor %}
```

---

Q: **"*Is there a way I can make ansible interpret \n as a new line and display it in the output?*"**

A: Yes. There is. Use a [callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback) that interprets the new lines, e.g.

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook playbook.yml

  msg: |-
    - Created VM - image-201
    - Created VM - image-202
```

What you see is JSON, probably the result of the *default* callback

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook playbook.yml

{
    "msg": "- Created VM - image-201\n- Created VM - image-202\n"
}
```

---

As a sidenote. It's possible to use Python *format*, e.g

```yaml
    - name: Show created VM's
      debug:
        msg: "{{ '{}'.format(_msg) }}"
      vars:
        _msg: |
          {% for item in azure_nic.results %}
          - Created VM - {{ item.invocation.module_args.tags.hostname }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That works but it doesn't show in new line. It shows in a single line with `\n` character. Created VM - image-201\n- Created VM - image-202\n

Comment: is there a way I can make ansible interpret `\n` as new line and display it in the output?

Comment: That worked thanks. I added `stdout_callback = yaml` to ansible.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for python-comfortable users :

Basically, it uses the python interpreter on the host machine in order to compose the string of text line by line, by printing its content into the stdout, then that content is registered as ansible variable.

```
    - name: Show created VM's
      block:

        - name: write the message using python
          command: /usr/bin/python
          args:
            stdin: |
              print(" ")  # this line is recommended but not mandatory
              print("Here are the VMs I created:")
              print(" ")

              vms_list = {{ azure_nic.results }}

              for item in vms_list:
                print("- Created VM - {}".format(item['invocation']['module_args']['tags']['hostname'] ) )

          register: enriched_string_msg
              
        # not really necessary as this will be printed as stdout during the previous task execution
        # - name: print the message using debug
        #   debug:
        #   msg: |
        #     {{ enriched_string_msg.stdout_lines }}
```